# Set margin-left (intended) for some rows of table

Tags: html, css

I want some rows (tr tag) of my table indented like this.

Not all rows, just some rows.
I think it must be margin because I want the border bottom indented too.

[image: expected]

Comment: Where is your code. Any image what do you want. Clear your question

Comment: I just add the picture

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: I tried to set margin-left, padding left but it not work as expected. I also searched for solutions but I didn't find. I just want to intended some rows, not all.

Comment: You can give  all tr a height and float them left.

Comment: Can you explain it? I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. It doesn’t help if you _say_ that you tried asomething and it “didn’t work”, if you don’t _show us_ what exactly you tried.

Answer (score 1):

**This may help you i think!**

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 4rem;
  border: 0.075rem solid #333;
  width: calc(20rem);
}

.in-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.row-name {
  position: relative;
}

.row-name::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  background: #333;
}

.items {
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <div class="row-name">Noob</div>
    <div class="items">
      <div>i want to code.</div>
      <div>but i don't want to write code.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <div class="row-name">Noob</div>
    <div class="items">
      <div>i want to code.</div>
      <div>but i don't want to write code.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <div class="row-name">Noob</div>
    <div class="items">
      <div>i want to code.</div>
      <div>but i don't want to write code.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks you @tawsif. but it's not my case. I'm using <table> and each line is an <tr> tag

Comment: why dont you get rid of table thing?tr ,th ,td, everytime check if you missed and 'tr' tags...yuck.just use div like me.okay, but as you wanted i am editting my code,till then hold my bear.

Comment: sorry as if i am not getting any clue, table behaves very weired

Comment: you can achieve the same thing with div tag easily than table.